# Def macro - scala 2.13 - not found: value cond

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I am trying to make working an example from the scala docs:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html

I have two files:

```
object Main extends App {

  println("Testing assert macro...")
  val result = Asserts.assert(true, "abc")

}
```

and:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context
import scala.language.experimental.macros

object Asserts {
  val assertionsEnabled: Boolean = true

  def assert(cond: Boolean, msg: Any): Unit = macro Asserts.assertImpl

  private def raise(msg: Any) = throw new AssertionError(msg)

  def assertImpl(c: Context)(cond: c.Expr[Boolean], msg: c.Expr[Any]) : c.Expr[Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    if (assertionsEnabled)
      c.Expr(q"if (!cond) raise(msg)")
    else
      c.Expr(q"()")
  }
}
```

but I am getting an error:

> Error:(8, 30) not found: value cond   val result =
> Asserts.assert(true, "abc")

any idea how to make it working ?
thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Macros and main code must be in different subprojects

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html

You missed dollar signs (`$cond`, `$msg` instead of `cond`, `msg`), otherwise while the macro is expanded inside `Main` you're trying to use absent local variables `cond`, `msg` rather than splice parameters `cond`, `msg` of the macro. Also it must be known inside `Main` that `raise` is `Asserts.raise` so either use `import Asserts.raise` in `Main` or fully qualified name in the quasiquote. Try

```
c.Expr(q"if (!$cond) Asserts.raise($msg)")
```

Also `Asserts.raise` must be accessible inside `Main` so remove `private`.